# Devise built in omniauth url helper causing undefined method error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, devise, omniauth, spree

I'm attempting to add facebook authentication to my rails app (which is built on Spree which has it's own authorization gem built on devise). I followed the steps at https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview
but it seems that devise isn't building the url helpers.

When I try to navigate to a page containing the link to authenticate with facebook,

```
<%= link_to "Sign in with Facebook", spree_user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook)%>
```

I get the following error:

```
undefined method `spree_user_omniauth_authorize_path' for #<#<Class:0x007ffc695c4fa0>:0x007ffc695a7798> 
Did you mean?  spree_user_registration_path
```

However, if I put in a trash url for that link and click on it, causing the rails routing error page to show up spree_user_omniauth_authorize_path is listed under the available routes.

Here's the relevant info from the spree authorization gem's routes.rb:

```
  devise_for :spree_user,
         :class_name => 'Spree::User',
         :controllers => { :sessions => 'spree/user_sessions',
                           :registrations => 'spree/user_registrations',
                           :passwords => 'spree/user_passwords',
                           :confirmations => 'spree/user_confirmations' },
         :skip => [:unlocks, :omniauth_callbacks],
         :path_names => { :sign_out => 'logout' },
         :path_prefix => :user
```

And here's the devise_for statement from my routes.rb

```
devise_for :spree_user,
          :class_name => 'Spree::User',
          :only => [:omniauth_callbacks]
```

I'm using devise 3.5.6, omniauth 1.3.1 and omnauth-facebook 3.0.0

What do I need to do to get this working?

Comment: And when you run rake routes does the spree_user_omniauth_authorize path show up?

Comment: Both the spree_user_omniauth_authorize and spree_user_omniauth_callback paths show up